# Fade out at specific scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can now fade in a  at a specific scroll height. But now I also want to fade out a  at specific scroll height. My code for the fade out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onscroll = function()
    {
    if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 25 || self.pageYOffset > 25) {
            $('.pulse').css('display','block');
        } else if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 25 || self.pageYOffset < 25) {
            $('.pulse').css('display','none');
    }
}
```

And  in css:

```
display: none;
```

How can I fade out a  at specific height?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions provided by jQuery:

```
//to show
$('.pulse').fadeIn(1000);
//to hide
$('.pulse').fadeOut(1000);
```

Docs of these functions:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/
http://api.jquery.com/fadein/